# Connect/Link jsp, servlet and java bean

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I really don't how to connect a JSP, Servlet and a Java bean together.

So the goal should be to type something into a textfield on the jsp which should be similar to an attribute in the bean. Then the content of the of the bean should be displayed on the jsp.

---

An example : The name "Max" gets entered into the texfield of the jsp.

In the bean there is an attribute called "String Max = "Peters";   "

Now the JSP should show: " The full name of Max is Max Peters. "

---

So, I've already got the bean, the servlet and the JSP file ready, I just don't know how to process the input.

I thought of using

Any ideas? First of all, is it the right way with the use of useBean?

Comment: What framework are you using, spring, struts ...?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean... I'm not a java pro

Comment: Maybe you should start with reading some tutorials, either here on SO ([Servlets](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/servlets/2857/getting-started-with-servlets#t=201611070820311889215), [JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jsp/1017/getting-started-with-jsp#t=20161107082004098278)), or directly at Oracle: [Java EE Web Tier](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadp.html)